# Infinite LibreOffice Draw file

Tags: libreoffice

I need to create a flowchart, and I like LibreOffice's Draw application. However, I can't create an large flowchart in it, since Draw is page-limited.

As seen in this [LibreOffice's forum topic](http://en.libreofficeforum.org/node/6990), I can't refer to it as "infinite page", but I want a "non-fixed size" document.

My need is to draw two graphs in parallel, and I'm used to do it in any web chart application, or even in Visio.

So, basically, I want to draw freely in a document, like in "Dia", but with LibreOffice's Draw interface and resources.

Is there anyway to do it?

Thank you in advance.